# What does 'cynical' mean - Stevens's dissent in Bush v Gore?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> "What must underlie petitioners' [Bush's] entire federal assault on the Florida election procedures is an unstated lack of confidence in the impartiality and capacity of the state judges who would make the critical decisions if the vote count were to proceed.  Otherwise, their position is wholly without merit.  The endorsement of that position by the majority of this Court can only lend credence to the most **cynical** appraisal of the work of judges throughout the land.  It is confidence in the men and women who administer the judicial system that is the true backbone of the rule of law."

This is from a dissent by Justice John P Stevens in *Bush vs Gore*. Which [definition](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/cynical) applies? Please explain the steps or thought processes, for want of doing so by myself in the future?

> `1.` Believing that people are motivated purely by self-interest
>   `1.2.` *Contemptuous; mocking*
>   `2.` Concerned only with one’s own interests and typically disregarding accepted standards...

For example, does Stevens mean 1.2 and implying that the majority's position can only "lend credence the most' *contemptuous, mocking* apparisal "of the ..."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He is saying that the majority decision demonstrates a belief that the state judges would act to advance their own "self-interest" rather than "accepted standards", if you understand "self-interest" here to mean "political interest" and "accepted standards" to mean "impartiality". That is, that a Democrat judge would rule in favor of a Democrat regardless of who was really in the right by objective, impartial standards.

Note this is a dissent in a highly controversial court decision. People who supported the majority decision would not agree with that assessment at all. But I don't suppose you're looking for a discussion of the meaning of the case but rather for the meaning of the sentence.

*Update*

By "he" I meant Justice Stevens, the author of the dissent.

The two definitions you list are variations on the same idea, but I was more specifically thinking of definition #2.

Comment: Thanks, so which definition applies? Would you please enlarge on how you chose this definition? Also, what's the antecedent of *he* in your topic sentence?

Comment: Will you please to respond  in your answer, and not as a comment?

Comment: Sorry for pinging you again, but I wanted to check that you received my messages?

Comment: I added the "Update" to my post. Did you miss that or did it not answer your question?

Comment: Sorry about that. I did miss your update, but thanks for replying.